# how to replace null JSON Array string value with empty string using retrofit 2?

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist, retrofit2

I am relatively new to Android development and am stuck in a problem. I am passing 3 parameters through header and am getting some values from JSON using Retrofit2 inside a response like this:

```
[
   {
    "SchemeCode": "202007.ABW.REG",
    "SchemeName": "202007.ABW.REG"
   }
]
```

If there is no response I receive null ([]). Here is the snippet for my retrofit call in order to get the String values:

```
sLabel.setOnClickListener(view1 -> {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
            View viewdialog = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.neworder_item_dialog, null);
            TextView schemeName = viewdialog.findViewById(R.id.schemeName);
            Call<ArrayList<SchemeModel>> call = apiInterface.showSchemes(cardCode, itemCode, date);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<SchemeModel>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(@NotNull Call<ArrayList<SchemeModel>> call, @NotNull Response<ArrayList<SchemeModel>> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()){
                        mList = response.body();
                        if (mList != null) {
                            for (int pos = 0; pos < mList.size(); pos++) {
                                String scheme = mList.get(pos).getSchemeName();
                                schemeCode = mList.get(pos).getSchemeCode();
                                schemeName.setText(scheme);
                            }
                        } else {
                            schemeCd = schemeCode.replace(null, "");
                        }
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NotNull Call<ArrayList<SchemeModel>> call, @NotNull Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
         });
```

Here, when I try to replace `null` with empty String `""` for `String schemeCd`, it just does not do it, saying that `ArrayList<SchemeModel> mList` is never null. Please help me replace `null` `schemeCd` value with empty String

Comment: String.replace(,) is a string function which takes two string parameters. You cannot put null in there. And null is not a string.

Comment: hi @Praveen that's fine, but how do I replace the incoming `null` value of `schemeCode` with `""` empty string and store in new String

Answer (score 0):

You are receving empty array ("[]") not null. just check "!mList.isEmpty()" instead of "mList != null"

Comment: hey @Tausif If I use check according to you, I get `Method invocation 'isEmpty' may produce 'NullPointerException' `  warning. and this doesn't answer my question. I want to replace the incoming `null` value of  `schemeCode` with `""` empty string and store in new `String`..